# Symfony controller: redirect, route or something else?

Tags: php, symfony

So I'm building a Symfony web app.

I have a simple controller (`DefaultController.php`) as follows:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
  /**
  * @Route("/", name="default")
  */
  public function defaultAction(){
    return $this->render('default/hello.html.twig', array(
      'name' => "hello"
    ));
  }
}
```

Nothing special.

Now, I would like to have a separate .php file called `APIController.php` that gets called when a user navigates to http://eamorr.com/api/

`APIController.php` would then handle requests such as:

- http://eamorr.com/api/getUser
- http://eamorr.com/api/addUser
- http://eamorr.com/api/getAllUsers
- ...

Here's what `APIController.php` should look like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class APIController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/getUser", name="getUser")
     */
    public function getUser(){
        //
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/addUser", name="addUser")
     */
    public function addUser(){
        //
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/getAllUsers", name="getAllUsers")
     */
    public function getAllUsers(){
        //
    }

    //etc.


}
```

From an architectural point of view, am I doing this right? Does anyone have any recommendations as to how to do this in Symfony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define routes like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/getUser", name="getUser")
 */
public function getUser(){
    //
}
```

Then the URL to this action will be `http://eamorr.com/getUser`. As you can see there's no `/api` part, and this is because you didn't mention it anywhere.

You have two solutions for this case.

First it to define full routes like

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/getUser", name="getUser")
 */
public function getUser(){
    //
}
```

Second: since you want all `APIController` actions to have this `/api` part, you can define a prefix for all routes by defining "base" route for whole class.

```
/**
 * @Route("/api", name="getUser")
 */
 class APIController extends Controller
```

Then you can leave your actions' routes like they are.

More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-prefix

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. But if you are looking to support multiple request and response formats (eg. JSON, XML) you are better off using [FOSRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html).

It can handle content negotiation, entity serialization (using [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) which is used by the FOSRest Bundle) and it let's you build RESTful routes.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks. I thought about FOSRestBundle, but I'm going to just annotate my functions and use apidoc.js to generate the docs and the sandbox. Actually, I'm going to try out all this in Laravel before deciding if Symfony really is for me. I need oauth too...

Comment: i can recommend http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/16/oauth2-explained-part-1-principles-and-terminology/ .
for api doc see the very useful https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle